# How to add a download button for a file uploaded by a user to a DataObject in the backend?

Tags: silverstripe

I want to add a download button to the backend of my `DataObject`.

I have an upload form on the front end where a user can upload a file. E.g a .jpg or .pdf.

```
class TeamPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'ContactForm'
        );

        $fields = new FieldList(array(
            TextField::create('Email'),
            FileField::create('MapFile')
        ));

        $actions = new FieldList(
            FormAction::create("doSaveSubmission")
        );

        $required = new RequiredFields('Email');

        $form = new Form($this, 'ContactForm', $fields, $actions, $required);

        return $form;


    }

    public function doSaveSubmission($data, $form){

        $submission = new ContactSubmission();
        $form->saveInto($submission);
        $submission->TeamPageID = $this->ID;
        $submission->write();

        return 'Saved into Dataobject';

    }




}
```

Now in the backend when you click through from the `Gridfield` into the individual entries I want to be able to download the file the user has uploaded. Is it possible to add a button next to the "Choose another file" button or create a button on its own that sits underneath that section of buttons:

[image]

**ContactSubmission.php**

```
<?php


class ContactSubmission extends DataObject
{

    private static $db = array(
        'Email' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'TeamPage' => 'TeamPage',
        'MapFile' => 'File'
    );


    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Email'
    );


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can customise the [`UploadField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-UploadField.html) buttons by creating a new template for `UploadField` to use. The default template it uses is `UploadField_FileButtons`. We will copy this to create our new template.

We create a template named *UploadField_FileButtonsWithDownload* in *mysite/templates/includes*. In this template we copy the original `UploadField_FileButtons`and add our download link on the end.

**UploadField_FileButtonsWithDownload.ss**

```
<% if $canEdit %>
    <button class="ss-uploadfield-item-edit ss-ui-button ui-corner-all" title="<% _t('UploadField.EDITINFO', 'Edit this file') %>" data-icon="pencil">
    <% _t('UploadField.EDIT', 'Edit') %>
    <span class="toggle-details">
        <span class="toggle-details-icon"></span>
    </span>
    </button>
<% end_if %>
<button class="ss-uploadfield-item-remove ss-ui-button ui-corner-all" title="<% _t('UploadField.REMOVEINFO', 'Remove this file from here, but do not delete it from the file store') %>" data-icon="plug-disconnect-prohibition">
<% _t('UploadField.REMOVE', 'Remove') %></button>
<% if $canDelete %>
    <button data-href="$UploadFieldDeleteLink" class="ss-uploadfield-item-delete ss-ui-button ui-corner-all" title="<% _t('UploadField.DELETEINFO', 'Permanently delete this file from the file store') %>" data-icon="minus-circle"><% _t('UploadField.DELETE', 'Delete from files') %></button>
<% end_if %>
<% if $UploadField.canAttachExisting %>
    <button class="ss-uploadfield-item-choose-another ss-uploadfield-fromfiles ss-ui-button ui-corner-all" title="<% _t('UploadField.CHOOSEANOTHERINFO', 'Replace this file with another one from the file store') %>" data-icon="network-cloud">
    <% _t('UploadField.CHOOSEANOTHERFILE', 'Choose another file') %></button>
<% end_if %>

<a class="ss-ui-button ui-corner-all" title="Download this file" href="$Link" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

We then set the `UploadField` template for the `MapFile` field to use our new template.

**ContactSubmission.php**

```
class ContactSubmission extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Email' => 'Varchar(255)'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'TeamPage' => 'TeamPage',
        'MapFile' => 'File'
    );


    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Email'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($mapFileField = $fields->fieldByName('Root.Main.MapFile')) {
            $mapFileField->setTemplateFileButtons('UploadField_FileButtonsWithDownload');
        }

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

Now a download button link should appear after the *Choose another file* button in the CMS.

Comment: Thanks @3dgoo for this its awesome. I have tried to implement it, however the download button is still not showing. The only thing I have different is the name of the file in the $has_one which I have changed to `'HousePlan' => 'File'` - But I have updated the $mapFileField to read `Root.Main.HousePlanID` - Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Root.Main.HousePlan` instead. I made a mistake putting `ID` on the end.

Comment: Nearly there, I am getting this php error now: `PHP Warning:  None of the following templates could be found (no theme in use): UploadField_FileButtonsWithDownload.ss in /theme-name/framework/view/SSViewer.php on line 816` and also
`[30-Nov-2015 14:58:59 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /theme-name/framework/view/SSViewer.php on line 1089` - I have made sure the template name is spelt correctly and it is located in `themes/themename/templates/Includes/UploadField_FileButtonsWithDownload.ss`

Comment: The template needs to be located in `mysite/templates/includes`, not in the theme folder, as this is used by the backend.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks once again! You are a silverstripe legend haha :)

Comment: @3dgoo do you know if there's a way to get the template file recognized by SS when it's in a module directory? mymodule/templates/Includes?

Comment: @csy_dot_io - Yes, that should work as long as it is a valid module directory. Make sure you call `?flush=all` in the admin section and the template file should work.

Comment: @3dgoo ah you are right. But I think it didn't work because I tried to overwrite the standard template cause I need this on every uploadfield. Is there a way to do that? Just naming the file like the original one and placing it in the module directory didn't work (in mysite it works)

Comment: @csy_dot_io - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103032/silverstripe).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new action on the DataObject form.

To do this, go and check out the Better Buttons Module. https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons

Within the action itself, you'll need to get SilverStripe to return the file with a forcedownload header. You can see someone else attempting this here..
http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/15832